# Debug print makes incomplete output of response body

Tags: flutter, http, dart, response

This is an output from `debugPrint(response)` in my app

```
<TABLE width="95%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="5"><TR valign="middle"><TD align="center"><A href="/index.php?page=gallery&action=show_photo&show_id=1&photo_id=2" class="amenu"><IMG src="/photos/_1.jpg" border="0" style="margin-bottom:3px"><BR>������, 45</A></TD><TD align="left"><SPAN class="small2">05.10.2020 14:30</SPAN><BR><A href="/index.php?page=account&action=read_letter&letter_id=446165541&return_folder=incoming" class="atitle">������</A><BR><BR><A href="/index.php?page=account&action=read_letter&letter_id=446165541&return_folder=incoming" class="amenu"><IMG border="0" src="/images/read_small.gif" align="absmiddle"> ������</A>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="javascript:OpenMiniWin('write_new.php?to_id=212535&subject=Re:������', 400, 450,'�������� ����� ������');" class="amenu"><IMG border="0" src="/images/reply_small.gif" align="absmiddle"> ��������</A>&nbsp;&n <!--there is something wrong here; there should be much more content which is not preset in the debugPrint output here-->
I/flutter (15253): google_ad_client = "ca-pub-2310428943483891";
I/flutter (15253): /* text letters */
I/flutter (15253): google_ad_slot = "8817281511";
I/flutter (15253): google_ad_width = 468;
I/flutter (15253): google_ad_height = 60;
I/flutter (15253): //-->
I/flutter (15253): </script>
```

There is a strange output there where is a `&nbsp;&n` - it is an incomplete output. In a real website response there should be `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` and then another content which is not present in the `debugPrint` output.

What's wrong with it?

Is debugPrint is able to hide some content? Or is it possible to check out the responce body content in some other way?

Comment: Android and iOS limit the length of lines printed to the system log.

Comment: @jamesdlin in the middle of the content (which is actually a string)?

Comment: Yes, Android and iOS will truncate lines that are too long.

Comment: @jamesdlin you are right, writing the response to file system give the full response content